# is it possible to declare what info is duplicated during subdivision?

Tags: texturing, vertex-colors, vertex-paint

I'm looking to write a script for fun and testing. I want to subdivide a mesh but only the vertex color info. In short, I want blender to create more room for uvless painting with out carrying twice the location and rotation info